# wrap word in span vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a funtion that return to me a list of word (with the previous and next qord). I am able to locate the word in the text correctly using a RegEx and knowing the previous and next word (so I find only one time the word and not all of the same). I am actually using the replace function of Javascript to wrap it inside a SPAN :

```
var re = RegExp("(?:^\\W*|(" + 
    motBefore.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&") + ")\\W+)" +
    motErreur.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\W+(" +
    motAfter.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&") + ")|\\W*$)", "g");
document.getElementById('edth_corps').innerHTML =
    document.getElementById('edth_corps').innerText
        .replace(re, motBefore + " " + '<span id="' + nbId +
        '" class="erreurOrthographe" ' +
        'oncontextmenu="rightClickMustWork(event, this);return false"> '
        + motErreur + '</span>' + " " + motAfter);
```

But the fact is that because I am placed on the group of these three word, I have to give him back the word before and after.

The issue I got with this tech is that I loose all punctuation and the more important , if there is a font tag (or bold, italic, underline) I loose them.

I'd like to wrap around this word a span like it is the child of the current node where this word is without touching the previous and next word (they are suposed to be here so we have the right word and not another occurence of this word).

But I have no idea how to do it since I can only use old Javascript (IE compiler is set to compatibily mode for IE5, and this function is the only one I can't manage to rewrite for this version). I can't use library such a Jquery (I have seen a lot of solution with this plug in).

Could someone point me in the right direction ? Could an insertBefore work even if the Error Word has no parent around him but is only part of a sentence ?

Comment: Can't I identify the parent tag with the search I do with the regEx then wrap a tag aroun this word without changing the position ? with and insertBeofre or another kind of insert ?

Comment: @JackA. but the wrod-wrap function seems to be only there so you can break a word if it is too long, no wrap it around a span

Comment: @JackA.when I use my function I can locate the word I need to wrap with a span (motErreur) but I have to give him the before and after word. What I would like is to just wrap the motErreur in span and give him as a child node without changing is position, like this if he is in the middle of the sentence he don't move, and if he is wrap already with like a bold tag, the span tag will became a child of this bold tag

Comment: Sorry, I totally misunderstood your question. Using `innerText` will definitely cause you to lose markup. I did something similar to this using the `TextRange` object (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535872(v=vs.85).aspx) a long time ago. I'll see if I can dig up the code when I get home tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer, but hopefully it will be useful. You can use the `TextRange` object in IE to modify the text in an element. This is similar to [the W3C Range object](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/), but it is supported by old versions of IE. Using this object, you can select text, find text, and modify the text.

Finding the desired text will be the tricky part, but once you've found it and selected it in a range, it is easy to modify the HTML.

As a simple example, I created [a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwc99asj/1/) that finds a string in a div and surrounds it with a span:

```
var findString = "JavaScript";
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
textRange.moveToElementText(content);
if (textRange.findText(findString)) {
  var html = "<span class='selected'>" + findString + "</span>";
  textRange.pasteHTML(html);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I am going to try it, using the RegEx I have I can find the global range then maybe use your answer to modify only the right word and not the word around him. I'll let you know how this worked for me.

Comment: Okay it's working greatly what you give to me, I have trouble integrating him with the regex I got but will keep working around what you gave me.

Comment: I just need to figure how to retrieve the parent Node with my RegEx and IE5 and It will be perfect I think